# How to groupby a row/horizontally (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Say one has a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','a','b','b','c','d', 'c'],
                   [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4]], index=["alpha", "val"])


        0   1   2   3   4   5   6
alpha   a   a   b   b   c   d   c
  val   1   3   5   7   9   2   4
```

Would we be able to group the data by `alpha`?

What I currently see from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) most examples are grouping by column labels. Still, there are lines like

> pandas objects can be split on any of their axes.
>
> # default is axis=0
>   grouped = obj.groupby(key)
>   grouped = obj.groupby(key, axis=1)    <- seems to be what we want
>   grouped = obj.groupby([key1, key2])

I tried with `df.groupby("alpha", axis=1)`, but it gave me `KeyError: 'alpha'` What is the correct way to do so?

This was one step in my another problem. In the problem, I tried to create

```
a b c d
1 5 9 2
3 7 4
```

Comment: You're looking for `df.groupby(df.loc['alpha'], axis=1)`. But what do you want to do?

Comment: Why don't you transpose the DataFrame first?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Originally, I was trying to solve other problems and this was a step in my approach. I was then want to stack values together. I edited it.

Comment: @Elmex80s that would also work.

Comment: @Tai Edited my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, if you want to group the val row by the `alpha` column, that's easy. You can pass series or lists as arguments to `groupby`.

Exhibit A -

```
df.loc['val'].groupby(df.loc['alpha']).sum()

alpha
a     4
b    12
c    13
d     2
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

If you're performing a grouping operation, specify `axis=1` -

```
df.groupby(df.loc['alpha'], axis=1).agg(...)
```

And here's the equivalent version with a transpose, as per Elmex80's comment, this is possible as well -

```
df.T.groupby('alpha').val.sum()

alpha
a     4
b    12
c    13
d     2
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

---

Based on your edit, call `groupby` + `apply` with a `pd.Series` argument, and then create a new dataframe.

```
v = df.loc['val'].groupby(df.loc['alpha']).apply(pd.Series.tolist)
```

Or,

```
v = df.T.groupby('alpha').val.apply(pd.Series.tolist)
```

Next,

```
pd.DataFrame(v.tolist(), index=v.index).T

alpha    a    b    c    d
0      1.0  5.0  9.0  2.0
1      3.0  7.0  4.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

So is this what you want ?

```
df.groupby(df.loc['alpha'],axis=1).sum()
Out[405]: 
alpha   a   b   c  d
alpha  aa  bb  cc  d
val     4  12  13  2
```

Edit

```
df=df.T
df.assign(key=df.groupby('alpha').cumcount()).pivot('key','alpha','val')
Out[418]: 
alpha  a  b  c     d
key                 
0      1  5  9     2
1      3  7  4  None
```

Comment: I have editted the question! Can you take another look? This is good enough though!

Comment: Nice answer as well! +1 :P

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of votes. Please wait for 1 and a half hours ;)